# When to use "hit" instead of "go"

Tags: meaning-in-context

In some movie I heard someone say "I am hitting now" when he was leaving. Did he use "hit" instead of "go"?

edit: "**I am hitting it**" is what I exactly heard in the movie. Two guys were sitting on a bench and one of them decided to leave.

Comment: Can you please provide more context? It's impossible for us to know what was the situation, the movie, the intention of the character if you don't say it and this makes it impossible for us to provide an answer.

Comment: If it was at night, you could also interpret "hitting it" as a shortening of "hitting the sack"; (i.e., going to sleep).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a shortening of *hit the trail*, or more recently *hit the road*. [Here's a chart](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=hit%20the%20trail,hit%20the%20road&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) showing how common these expressions are for *leave, get going*.

[image]

In these usages, *hit* primarily refers to physical contact between your feet and the trail/road, but figuratively, horse's hooves/car's 'boots' (tyres) can make [vicarious](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&newwindow=1&q=vicarious&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=6upaTp7RKIei8QP70KGNDA&sqi=2&ved=0CBsQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=f96c812afbc73ab3&biw=1423&bih=838) contact for you.

As @bracho monacho says, it's impossible for us to know whether the speaker simply meant he was leaving *(hitting the road)*, or going somewhere to sleep *(hitting the sack)*. If he *was* intending to sleep, it's quite possible the speaker himself didn't really care which meaning he was shortening.

Comment: the chart is really nice :)

Comment: @Maysam: I thought it was interesting to see how *road* has replaced *trail*, so your comment has encouraged me to put the actual chart into the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Are you sure the person didn't say "I am hitting it now"? The phrase "hit it" is a colloquialism that means *leave* or *depart*. It may be a shortened form of "hit the road".

Comment: Can it be used for any kind of departure? Could you please give more examples in context?

Comment: @Maysam: Frankly, I wouldn't use "hit it" at all if I were you. Specify "the road" or "the sack", or there's a good chance people either won't know what you meant at all, or will think that your choice of expressions is odd.